# angular ui grid date filter to search the date in column

Tags: angularjs, date, angular-ui-grid, datefilter

I wanted to search the date in my search column, using angular ui date filter.

When i try to search my date in the column, its not showing the correct date.
I want it to show the exact match of user search.
Example: If user types 22-aug-16, it should show only date matching to this date, suppose if users types 25-aug alone it should show only dates matching 25th august in any year that is present in the database.

I tried with my code like,

```
.controller(
                'BlockADetailsController',
                [
                        '$scope', '$rootScope','$location','$routeParams', '$filter', 'CommonService', 'BlockADetailsService', '$q',
                        function($scope, $rootScope,$location, $routeParams, $filter, CommonService, BlockADetailsService, $q) {
$scope.changeActorGridOptions = {
enableFiltering : true,
columnDefs : [
                                            {
{
                                                name : 'lLDate',
                                                field : 'lLDate',                                               
                                                displayName : 'LAST_LOGIN',                                         
                                                width : '100',
                                                minWidth: '90',
                                                cellTemplate : '<div title="{{COL_FIELD | date:\'dd-MMM-yy\' }}">{{COL_FIELD | date:"dd-MMM-yy"  }}</div>',
                                                headerTooltip : true,
                                                cellClass : function(grid, row,
                                                        col, rowRenderIndex,
                                                        colRenderIndex) {
                                                    return 'gridGroupCell';
                                                },
                                                headerCellFilter : 'translate',                                         
                                            },
```

Here i also tried with

```
type: 'date'
```

And also added the onselect function which is mentioned in the same kind of question in stackoverflow.

Like,

```
onSelect: function(date){
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                       ngModel.$setViewValue(date);
                    });
                }
```

Please help me in this, hope i explained my requirement. Kindly show some assistance for it.

This is the column field where i am doing the search,

[Here i want to search my required date, it has to show only the relevant.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISvJm.png)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me,

```
{
                                            name : 'lLDate',
                                            field : 'lLDate',                                               
                                            displayName : 'LAST_LOGIN',                                             
                                            type : 'date',
                                            cellFilter : 'date:"dd-MMM-yy"',
                                            filterCellFiltered : 'true',
                                            width : '100',
                                            minWidth: '90',
                                            cellTemplate : '<div title="{{COL_FIELD | date:\'dd-MMM-yy\' }}">{{COL_FIELD | date:"dd-MMM-yy"  }}</div>',
                                            headerTooltip : true,
                                            cellClass : function(grid, row,
                                                    col, rowRenderIndex,
                                                    colRenderIndex) {
                                                return 'gridGroupCell';
                                            },
                                            headerCellFilter : 'translate',                                                 
                                        },
```

Comment: It throws an error ```Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/unpr?p0=translateFilterProvider[object Object]3C-%6translateFilter````

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom filter function for matching date and applied it in 'condition' field,PFB the columnDef for the field :

```
{ 
            name: 'orderDate',
            enablePinning: false,
            enableSorting: true,
            sort: { direction: 'asc' },
            width: "15%",
            displayName: 'Order Date',
            cellClass: 'pr25',
            filterCellFiltered:true,
            cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd"',
            filterHeaderTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-filter-container" ng-repeat="colFilter in col.filters"><input type="date" class="ui-grid-filter-input" ng-model="colFilter.term" /></div>',
            filters:[
            { 
            filterName: "equalsTo",
            condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
              var strippedValue = (cellValue + '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '-');
                var d1= new Date(strippedValue);
                var d2= new Date(searchTerm);
                return (
                    d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
                    d1.getDate() === d2.getDate()
                 );
              },
            placeholder: 'equals'
          }]

        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter condition to the column to check for less or greater than conditions. If you just want to check for exact date string match use the following as the filter condition.

```
filter: {
          condition: uiGridConstants.filter.CONTAINS,
          placeholder: 'placeholder'
        },
```

This plnkr shows the filter condition with date matching

http://plnkr.co/edit/a9W4Gy7oUpdqieQjEw1A?p=preview

Comment: Hi. thanks for the help.
But this is not working for me.
I tried adding these three lines in my columnDefs, it worked for me.
type : 'date',
            cellFilter : 'date:"dd-MMM-yy"',
            filterCellFiltered : 'true',